# How to save a column after selecting it in R

Tags: r

Doing the problem 'Selecting Columns' in the lesson 'Introduction to data frames in R' on codeacademy.

It asks "Select the `group` column of `artists` using `select()` and save the result to `artist_groups`. View `artist_groups`."

I know how to select the column, it just doesn't tell me how to save it.

```
artists %>%
  select(group)
```

I'm guessing I use `artist_groups <-` in some way but I can't get it to work

Comment: Use the `tee` from `magrittr` or just use `->` at the end ie `my_selection_code -> artist_groups`?

Comment: Yeah, the second one worked. Thanks! I knew it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Put it before your code, this is an example with the dataset 'trees'

```
column <- trees %>%
              select(Volume)
```

In your data would be

```
artist_groups <- artists %>%
                    select(group)
    View(artist_groups) # And view the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
    install.packages("dplyr")
    library(dplyr)

    artist_groups <- artists %>%
                        select(group)
```